# MySQL per user monitoring

Tags: mysql, munin, monitoring

Is there a tool for monitoring **per user MySQL usage**? Like number of queries for example. I have been looking on Munin which I currently use, but did not find anything. A similar tool is the per user CPU usage monitoring: http://exchange.munin-monitoring.org/plugins/cpubyuser/details

Answer (score 1):

Will http://www.ubuntugeek.com/mytop-top-like-query-monitor-for-mysql.html help at all?